# Constructors : difference between defaulting and delegating a parameter

Tags: c++, std, c++14

Today, I stumbled upon [these standard declarations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) of `std::vector` constructors :

```
// until C++14
explicit vector( const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
// since C++14
vector() : vector( Allocator() ) {}
explicit vector( const Allocator& alloc );
```

This change can be seen in most of standard containers. A slightly different exemple is `std::set` :

```
// until C++14
explicit set( const Compare& comp = Compare(),
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
// since C++14
set() : set( Compare() ) {}
explicit set( const Compare& comp,
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

What is the difference between the two patterns and what are their (dis)advantages ?
Are they strictly equivalent - does the compiler generate something similar to the second from the first ?

Comment: You say "STL" containers. Do you mean the signature of these standard library container member functions as mandated by the standard itself, or the code of some specific implementation?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I mean the former : I assume the signatures of these functions are standard (en.cppreference.com says that there is a change coming from the standard - "since C++14").

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I do not really understand what to edit ; is "STL" wrong ? For me, it is the part of the standard library that uses templates (hence standard "template" library). Or is it something else ?

Comment: After a bit of research, I see what you mean. However, it seems that the "stdlib" tag is automatically changed to "std" which is also about Ruby and has significantly less followers and questions than the "std" tag. Quite misleading.

Comment: Never mind; didn't spot the link to cppreference.com. That's enough to show that you're talking about the standard signatures and not some wibbly wobbly non-compliant implementation code.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The difference is that

```
explicit vector( const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

is `explicit` even for the case where the default argument is used, while

```
vector() : vector( Allocator() ) {}
```

is not. (The `explicit` in the first case is necessary to prevent `Allocator`s from being implicitly convertible to a `vector`.)

Which means that you can write

```
std::vector<int> f() { return {}; }
```

or

```
std::vector<int> vec = {};
```

in the second case but not the first.

See [LWG issue 2193](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2193).

Comment: If the explicit keyword is dropped, I assume that an Allocator could be implicitly converted to a vector ?

Comment: Ooh this is far more interesting than I expected when reading the question.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this means that *any* type with a non-explicit default constructor can be "constructed from `{}`", ie. makes some sense of a "void element". I agree with @LightnessRacesinOrbit here, this is far more interesting than expected.

Comment: @Alex I'm not sure what you mean by "void element"; you get a default constructed object. Perfectly normal. The difference is that you can do it by initialising from just `{}` rather than having to explicitly write `vector()` or somesuch.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Sorry if this was unclear: I mean something like a "zero element". Like an empty container or string, a numerical zero, a null pointer, etc. This may prove useful in template contexts. Also, being able to write `{}` for any empty container is quite useful.

Comment: Over the years I'd forgotten all about this (and even [re-asked it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49214277/560648) in a triumph of "parallel evolution") — currently writing C++11 using GCC 4.8 and could swear I've used this initialisation form for standard containers. Interesting.