# Why did set's constructor change in C++14?

Tags: c++, c++14

While answering a question, I noticed that [`std::set`'s constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/set) changed in C++14:

```
// Until C++14:
explicit set( const Compare& comp = Compare(), 
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );

// Since C++14:
set() : set( Compare() ) {}
explicit set( const Compare& comp, 
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

I can't figure out what functional difference this makes, other than speculating that it could have something to do with some fancy metaprogramming that requires an honest-to-gods default constructor to do its work.

**Why was this change made?**

Comment: @SombreroChicken Pretty sure T.C.'s answer addresses the why.

Comment: Er apparently I even commented on that answer at the time lol